# Firebase, Typescript, request progress : how to display a request progress?

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observable, angular-material2

I am using `angularfire2` in my Angular project , along with Angular Material.

I thought it would be nice to let the user know the request is being processed.

Without using Firebase, I know I can use `Interceptors` to handle this kind of things. But with Firebase, they don't work anymore.

So I've decided to make a service that will make all my HTTP call, and make it behvae like an interceptor.

My issue is that when you create a request, the Observable created never ends. This means I can show a progress status, but never hide it.

For instance, I have this method, that returns every document of a collection :

```js
getCollection<T>(collection: string, query?: QueryFn): Observable<T[]> {
  return (query ? this.db.collection<T>(collection, query) : this.db.collection<T>(collection)).valueChanges();
}
```

**How would one do to show a progress bar when the application is fetching the collection ?**

I usually went by something like this

```js
getCollection<T>(collection: string, query?: QueryFn): Observable<T[]> {
  this.loading = true;
  return (query ? this.db.collection<T>(collection, query) : this.db.collection<T>(collection)).pipe(finalize(() => this.loading = false));
}
```

But `valueChanges` prevents that.

Answer (score 1):

If your observable never complete, you can use the tap operator. This operator is used to perform an action when your stream emits new values without side effect :

```
getCollection<T>(collection: string, query?: QueryFn): Observable<T[]> {
  this.loading = true;
  return (query ? this.db.collection<T>(collection, query) : this.db.collection<T>(collection)).pipe(tap(() => this.loading = false));
}
```

EDIT : If you want to mimic a standard API behavior. You can use the `.take` operator.

example :

```
getCollection<T>(collection: string, query?: QueryFn): Observable<T[]> {
  this.loading = true;
  return this.db.collection<T>(collection, query)
    .pipe(
        take(1),
        finalize(() => this.loading = false)
    );
}
```

With this `take` operator, your observable will complete after first data emission. But as I Said in the comment it break the concept of `fireStore`, cause if you add another item to the collection, you will need to call again the `getCollection` to get a new `Observable`.

btw : it seems your ternary is useless (but I dont really know firebase) . Change :

```
return (query ? this.db.collection<T>(collection, query) : this.db.collection<T>(collection)).pipe(tap(() => this.loading = false));
```

to

```
return this.db.collection<T>(collection, query).pipe(tap(() => this.loading = false));
```

Comment: I will try about the ternary, but back to the main topic : in your example case, the `tap` operator only sets the loading to false. This means if a value is emitted, then the loading is never true, is it ? From what I see, it only sets it to false, while I would have it set to **true then false** when a new value is emitted. Do you have a solution for that ? Anyway, upvote for the `tap` operator which I didn't know, thank you !

Comment: An observable is never fetching a data. It only transfers a flow of data. You have a "lag" between the moment you get the observable from this.db.collection("whatever") and the moment this observable emit the first data. So you can display a loading status on the startup. But after this, since your Observable don't fetch data, you cant have a loading status. After is you want to mimic a REST API behavior you can just add take(1) in your db.collection pipe. With this, the Observable will complete after the first emit. But is kind of break fireStone concept I think.

Comment: Sorry if I'm using the wrong words. So if I understood correctly, you're saying that there's only one event after the first data emit ? This means if I would mimic a loading at every value emit, I should mock a call with a Timeout ? And I can stop at the first value emitted with a `subscribe` apparently (it works like a charm, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice)

Comment: i put an example of a possible usage of take operator. But i dont think its a good idea :|